# How to get my question re-opened?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

I recently asked this question [Are there USB-A to USB-C adapters for the Early 2015 MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170938/macbook-air-usb-c-to-usb-a) and it was closed as "primarily opinion-based" due to there not being enough detail since it was all rumours then. Now the 12″ Air has been launched, could we re-open it? This is because there's more official detail about it and if not there will be soon.

Comment: Thanks for raising the issue on meta. I'll have a look and let you know...

Comment: Also - you will want to be clear if you are asking about the MacBook that's announced but not for sale as opposed to the MacBook Air that you can buy today and has legacy sized USB ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stands, it's both opinion-based and off topic. We are for practical questions about shipping hardware. I would say you can edit to ask more "how to determine how USB-C works and less dependent on Apple releasing a modified MacBook Air in 2015.

The short answer, is no one can order any Apple product with USB C so there's not much benefit to the site to have a speculative discussion question open. If and when hardware is orderable and/or announced with technical details - flag that question for moderator review if you don't have the reputation to cast a reopen vote.

If you were to change this to be - is there anything in the [USB-C connector specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#TYPE-C) that makes it impossible to plug in a [Standard A USB connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Connector_types) - I couldn't see keeping it closed.

Basically, when you have a hardware purchase dilemma, ask here how to educate yourself to understand the technology directly. Illuminate that core question with the hardware you wish to buy - but make the question about how does one learn to understand [protocol | connector | software | performance benchmarking | etc... ] so that you can make a good decision.

Shopping questions that revolve around price, avaiability, or soft generalizations (e.g. Which MacBook for a developer) get closed as off-topic and/or opinion based.

Cheers and welcome to the site. I look forward to learning about USB C as well.

Comment: So could I edit the question to ask if there are any USB-C to USB-A adapters since the 12" MacAir uses USB-C and not USB-A? or would it be better to ask it as a new question? That is unless it's better asking on SuperUser (or other SE site) if there are any USB-C to USB-A adapters.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper  Just start editing - there's no penalty for making two or three tries to refine it. Each edit gets it entered into a queue where high reputation users can see what you're doing and vote to reopen. Don't ask a new question - just edit it heavily if needed. Once it's in shape and has details - we can land it on SU if needed.